# How to bind wxTreeItemId as a data type in a sqlite3 database?

Tags: c++, sqlite, wxwidgets

I want to make column to insert `wxTreeItemId` as the value, I saw this datatype `BLOB` in sqlite that takes data as it is, but I'm not sure what `sqlite3_bind_blob()` takes as the parameters, I have a function updates the column for `wxTreeItemId` as,

```
{
    try
    {
        rc = sqlite3_open("Samples.db", &DB);

        std::string select = "UPDATE SAMPLES SET FAVORITEFOLDER = ? WHERE FILENAME = ?;";

        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(DB, select.c_str(), select.size(), &stmt, NULL);

---->   rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(sqlite3_stmt *, int, const void *, int n, void (*)(void *))

        rc = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, Filename.c_str(), Filename.size(), SQLITE_STATIC);

        if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            wxLogDebug("Record found, updating..");
        }

        rc = sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

        if (rc != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            msgDialog = new wxMessageDialog(NULL, "Error! Cannot update record.", "Error", wxOK | wxICON_ERROR);
            msgDialog->ShowModal();
            sqlite3_free(ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            wxLogDebug("Updated record successfully.");
        }

        sqlite3_close(DB);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &exception)
    {
        wxLogDebug(exception.what());
    }
}
```

I want to know what those parameters are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

`wxTreeItemId` is basically a pointer internally, so it makes no sense to store it in a database. If you need to save a reference to a tree item, you need to use the path to it, e.g. a sequence of its positions among its siblings or something similar.

Comment: I see, looking around I found this, `wxDataViewTreeCtrl` which even has more control over if a item is a child or container. Can this be used for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You've never actually explained what were you trying to do.

Comment: I have a application which has a `wxDataViewListCtrl`, when user adds a audio file to the application, its information gets inserted to different columns of `wxDataViewListCtrl` like title, path, length and all. There is also a toggle column, when user toggles it on it adds that item/file to `wxTreeCtrl`, and in that tree view I have a button that adds a item as kind of a folder, that when selected should get tagged as folder associated with file which the user toggles on the column in `wxDataViewListCtrl`, which is why I'm trying to store `wxTreeItemId` in database as folder for that file.

Comment: So I can load the database back when user closes and re opens the application. So this `wxDataViewTreeCtrl` has a container and child as separate items, so I think I can use this better for my needs, containers as folders, and child as items inside it. Can I store container information which is `wxDataViewItem` in the database?

Comment: No, you still need to store paths as explained above. If you think about it, what do you think a `wxDataViewItem` is, actually?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by paths and positions? How do I get those values?

Comment: You can identify each item in a tree by a path to it from the root. The simplest way is to use the index among its siblings as the path component at each level. You will need to construct these paths yourself.